# How to make BEM less obsuse

Tags: javascript, sass, workflow, bem

I’ve started using BEM on some projects and find it a little unwieldy to write within my HTML. I was trying to make it simple so I have to repeat myself less when I’m writing classes for each element and apply some structure with JS that would force me to do this properly. The output would be something like:

```
<div class="intro intro--red">
   <h1 class="intro__title">Title</h1>
   <p class="intro__p">Text</p>
   <p class="intro__p intro__p--red">Text</p>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn--red">Link</a>
</div>
```

but written shorter and simpler like:

```
<div b="intro" m="red">
   <h1 e="title">Title</h1>
   <p>Text</p>
   <p m="red">Text</p>
   <a href="#" b="btn" m="red">Link</a>
</div>
```

This way I could have named elements or it can give me classes based on the html element if none are set. This would then hopefully help keep my sass nice and clean and be really quick to type. I attempted a [basic implementation](https://codepen.io/smongey/pen/zRbxwp) but I think there may be a better way to do this or I might be doing something I shouldn't using html attributes like that?

Any wisdom or pointers would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue using BEM. My solution was to make my code a form of BEM but not 100% according BEM guidelines.

What i did is something like this:

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="intro-title">
        <p class="red">Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So things like colors would get global helpers, then a bunch of helpers for simple styling like font sizes or spacing etc.

For the actual intro block this is how my sass would look like:

```
Intro.scss
.intro {
    &-title {
        float: left;
    }
}

Helpers.scss
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

As you can see you can go as deep with the nesting of sass as you want, i keep the rule of max 3 levels deep.

It's not a 100% BEM approach but it's a form off :)

Hope that helps you.

I would also avoid putting these custom attributes on html and parsing things with JS, when it comes to these things me personally I'm a bit of a purist and HTML is not meant for this so i wouldn't use it. Plus potential content flickers when loading the css through JS and keeping performance in mind as well. But it's totally your own preference, just giving you a pointer in how i solved this issue that works for me.